# Which will be the best free VFX software for an absolute beginner?

Tags: video, video-editing

I am absolutely new to VFX designing and I have tried my hands on Blender, which I find quite useful. I tried After Effects, but couldn't do anything due to its complexity.

I want to know about a program with which I can do simple editing cool stuff like say, create a virtual light-saber, or an action movie effect like plane crash etc. in my videos?

Comment: Good visual effects often require quite a bit of power and complexity. I can't think of any "beginner" options, free or otherwise, that could do decent light sabers or compositing for a plane crash. Perhaps you could increase your knowledge via tutorials to become more familiar with After Effects or Blender?